# How to handle extra data in symfony form?

Tags: php, symfony

I have entity called Project, it has `name` and `members` property. Members referencing to `User` entity but never mind.
I'm wondering how to handle extra data that passed as json through API.

I would like to pass such as json code:

```
  {
    "project": {
      "name": "Testowy project",
      "members": [
        "chester58@boehm.com",
        "someotherhuman@gmail.com"
      ],
      "members_roles": {
        "chester58@boehm.com": "user",
        "someotherhuman@gmail.com": "admin"
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, there is member_roles property, but in the entity there is none. I'm not sure if should I set allow_extra_fields as true in form's options and handle it independently – if so, is possible to restrain extra fields only for chosen fields?

I hope I am enough clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the field in the form type and set the option `mapped` to `false`.

You will have access to be submitted value through `$form->get('fieldName')->getData()` or via form events.

[Form option: mapped](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped)

Comment: Thank you. I know this is possible to do, but I would rather know if this is the right apporach. I'm just wondering whether should I handle extra data from form type or right from the request?

Comment: In my opinion, if you have to handle entity extra data, you have to replace the entity form by a command form (CQRS), so, it will be easier to manipulate and process

Comment: I though about that, but finally rejected this concept. I don't thing the extra data in the form is forcing me to use CQRS tho.